# Integrating dlib into a Xamarin android project

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, dlib

I am very new to C# and Xamarin, I am trying to implement the following Git repo(https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android/blob/master/README.md) in a Xamarin android application. I have created a Java binding Project for android Using Visual Studio and added a .jar file from the git repo to the jars directory in the Binding project.  when I try build the solution the build breaks after generating C# code and then I am receiving errors in the auto generated code.
These are the errors I am receiving:

CS0535  'AbstractCommandLineConverter' does not implement interface member 'ICommandLineConverter.Convert(ParsedCommandLine, Object)'

CS0535  'AbstractCommandLineConverter' does not implement interface member 'ICommandLineConverter.Convert(ParsedCommandLine, Object)'

CS0534  'AbstractPropertiesCommandLineConverterInvoker' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AbstractCommandLineConverter.NewInstance()'

```
CS0534  'SystemPropertiesCommandLineConverter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AbstractCommandLineConverter.NewInstance()'
```

can any one help with these errors or point me in the right direction to resolve these errors, it would be much appreciated.

many thanks in advance

since I am new to c# I have tried out the suggested solutions by visual studio, but I am not sure that this is right. and even After trying the suggested solutions I still end up with this error

CS1715  'AbstractPropertiesCommandLineConverterInvoker.NewInstance1': type must be 'IDictionary<string, string>' to match overridden member 'AbstractPropertiesCommandLineConverter.NewInstance1'